# NullReferenceException despite gameObject correctly found and components correctly in place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a simple 2D game with unity, and started getting the error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` even though the code was previously running fine.
The error is related to a script controlling the health bar of the character:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class healthBarScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;

    void Start()
    {
        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
        Debug.Log(slider);
    }

    public void SetMaxHealth(int maxHealth)
    {
        slider.maxValue = maxHealth;
        slider.value = slider.maxValue;
    }

    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.value = health;
    }

}
```

Which is called by the player script in the `awake()` function:

```
    void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        healthBar = GameObject.Find("HealthBar").GetComponent<healthBarScript>();
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }
```

I have determined that the line `slider.maxValue = maxHeath;` is causing the issue: slider is not found when calling `SetMaxHealth` even though `slider` is correctly fetched in the `Start()` call. The reason for this is that the `Awake` function of the Player script is called before the `Start` of the healthbar script. How can I solve this?

Comment: My number one thumb rule is: **Use `Awake`** for initializing all your own values and components where you don't rely on anithing else being initilaized yet. **Use `Start`** for initializing anything where you do rely on others having initialized themselves (in `Awake`) first. This covers most of the cases ... if this it not enough you have to start using `event` callbacks ;)

Comment: @Igor [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) are called by the Unity message system itself ;)

Comment: In your case this means my solution would be convert the `healthBarScript.Start` to `Awake` so it only initializes itself first. And then move the `healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);` into `Start`